# Using Arduino input switches to turn on Arduino and WS2812B at the same time to reduce standby current using MOSFETs

Tags: power-supply, arduino, power, mosfet, switching

Despite 20 years of experience with electronics, I can't seem to figure out what type of circuit to use in this case. There are 6 input switches which need to be used to switch on the Arduino itself and a WS2812B LED strip at the same time to reduce standby current.

Another option is to use relays, but those would need to be placed outside of the existing enclosure due to size and would result in too many wires being used.

Basically I need to switch on a logic-level P-channel MOSFET by applying +5 V at the gate. I could only find auto-power-off circuit examples activated by a separate push button for Arduino. In this case the same input switches need to be used to turn the power supply on and off.

Added some block diagram to see what is required.

Since the arduino is being used for sequential turn signals, brake lights and drl on a bicycle then using auxiliary switches would result in too much wiring and would require additional means of switching (relay, etc) since brake lights are using reed switches. Currently planning to use IRF7420PbF due to it's low profile. Using just a single mosfet with multiple gate inputs would be the best option since multichannel solid state relays are too big. Hard to find any practical circuits despite arduino and ws2812b being widely used in general and in battery powered applications. Added some block diagram to see what is required. https://ibb.co/C8fFy0j

Doodled a quick circuit with diode OR gate wnich also isolates each input between another. Will see if it work somehow since I'm more familiar with troubleshooting instead of designing circuits for highly "specialised" applications.
By the way diodes are accidentally reversed in this drawing.

https://ibb.co/FhG53b7

Comment: Is it enough to use the sleep mode of the microcontroller and interrupts to wake it up?

Comment: If you want to turn power off to everything with a power switch, why do you need a FET? Just use the power switch to connect or disconnect the power supply to the circuit directly.

Comment: Since the arduino is being used for sequential turn signals, brake lights and drl on a bicycle then using auxiliary switches would result in too much wiring and would require additional means of switching (relay, etc) since brake lights are using reed switches. Currently planning to use IRF7420PbF due to it's low profile. Using just a single mosfet with multiple gate inputs would be the best option since multichannel solid state relays are too big. Hard to find any practical circuits despite arduino and ws2812b being widely used in general and in battery powered applications.

Comment: how is standby current reduced when the two devices are switched on at the same time?

Comment: The devices are not used all the time while touring on a bicycle, only when braking and turning. Could use hd107s with reduced standby current but that would require reconfiguration  from 6 led strips to 3 and reprogramming since there are two data wires.

Comment: Please in-line your schematic.

Comment: The link for schematic is in the main question.